# how add a native datepicker in ionic project?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

If I do:

```
<input type="date">
```

I have this datepicker:

[image]

And I need the natives like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are running your app in the browser, that's why the date picker looks like that. 
Just run your app on an emulator or a real device to get the native date picker.

Comment: In the emulator and in the device, it give somethinglike this: https://puu.sh/t9PIb/dcd67d2466.png

Comment: Looks good! Are you trying to obtain something different than that?

Comment: Yes I want to obtain the second image of my question

Comment: That image looks like the iOS native date picker so to get it you have to run your app on an iOS emulator or device.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Native date-picker, you should use the cordova plugin.
Take into account that I will render differently according to the platform.

https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Comment: what do you mean by alone? Take into account you wont be able to test it in your local browser, it must be deployed to a phone.

Comment: I think, juste using <input type="date">, no need to add some other attributes?

Comment: You have to trigger the date picker manually: check this eample http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/